# PHP | Compare two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

**$arr_order:**

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 5
                [id] => 2
                [sku] => Model 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 2
                [id] => 3
                [sku] => Model 1
            )
    )
```

**$arr_stock:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [qty] => 2
        )

)
```

How can I compare these two arrays using a `foreach` loop?

Example:
If `$arr_order[0][qty] =5 > $arr_stock[0][qty] = 2 ...`

returns third array:

**$arr_stock_available:**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [qty] => 2
            )
    )
```

Comment: Hint: `foreach ($arr_order as $i => $val) $arr_stock[$i]['qty'] ...`

Comment: Use array_diff to get the diferences: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$arr_stock_available = array();
foreach($arr_order as $data){
   if($data['qty'] > $arr_stock[$i]['qty']){
       $arr_stock_available[] = $arr_stock[$i];
    } else {
       $arr_stock_available[] = $data;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Use the above code.

Comment: For one, you're never incrementing `$i`, secondly the OP wanted the difference between the stock values.

Comment: @deceze I have modified the code. But not found anywhere that OP want the difference of stock values.

Comment: @user889349 if you want only the result as you show the above then remove the else part from my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Else condition can be removed.